# WKInterfaceController cancel button

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

Is there any way to know when the cancel/dismiss button is tapped on the Apple Watch?

```
- (void)didDeactivate
```

Is not an option because that is called whenever the watch goes dark. I'm trying to sync data with the parent iPhone app and this makes it tough to cancel an operation on the parent app.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

While you can't get the cancel directly, you can tell which view controller is active (because your code displayed it) and then tell when they switch.  So you can set some flags on display and on de-activate, to tell when the view controller with the cancel button goes away.

Think of it another way, if your view controller disappears and another one displays, the activate of the other controller tells you the watch did not sleep.

Comment: This will not work because the - (void)didDeactivate is called when the watch goes dark or when a user taps the crown.

Comment: Yes, but another view controller will not activate then.  So you can tell the difference.

Comment: I'm talking about the controllers in the WatchKit  extension, not ViewControllers in the iOS app. There is no other Controller activating, the screen is going to sleep.

Comment: What @Cobra is suggesting could work. He is saying to keep activate flag of all `WKInterfaceController` objects that are pushed/presented and check which one is at the top. Is this correct @Cobra?

Comment: Yes, that is one way.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the current version of WatchKit has no method to determine if the `Cancel` button is tapped. The closest you'll get is the `didDeactivate` event that you've already mentioned.